# How to sign into UWP app with microsoft account?

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp, in-app-purchase, azure-mobile-services

I am designing a uwp c# app that contains in app purchases. This app will be installed on public systems, so I want the app to pop up with a sign in screen when it starts. I want users to sign in with their microsoft accounts, so that they can make purchases on their account.

I am following the instructions for this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users . To sign in with Microsoft, you need to "configure your preferred identity provider" and for microsoft, the instructions are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-microsoft .

The second website tells you to add a domain name for your app, But I dont know what that Is.

`In Redirect URIs, select Web, and then type https://<app-domain-name>/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback supply the endpoint for your application. Replace <app-domain-name> with the domain name of your app. For example, https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback.`

What would be my redirect URI for my app? also, are there any code samples of this so that I can see how it works better?

Comment: In general, when the internal purchase behavior occurs in the app, the system will automatically call the Microsoft account login interface. If you want to actively log in, it is a question of calling azure mobile service, you may need to ask azure related personnel.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT My app is installed on a public machine, and each user will need to sign in with their credentials. when you try to purchase an in app purchase, it a window pops up asking you to sign in, but only to enter your password, not to enter your account, and even when you enter multiple accounts in windows settings, the app defaults to the first one, so i am hoping that microsoft graph will pass users info in for the iap. I got graph working, but cant chage scopes. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108384/unable-to-change-scopes-in-uwp-sample-microsoft-graph)

Comment: If the IAP is a durable add-on, then no matter which user purchases the IAP on A device, all users on A device will be able to launch the APP and have the add-on directly. In this way, even if you switch to a different user to log in, it makes no sense.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT My IAP is Consumable, store managed. Is it possible to have the user sign in with ms-graph? the prompt that pops up with the iap doesnt let you change users, and you cant in windows either, so it must be done in app Right?

Comment: IAP users and ms-graph logins are different. But you can try it.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT How do I change the user for an IAP?

Comment: If you want to change the user, you need to go to the Microsoft Store to sign out the user. And as I said before, If someone purchases the product in this machine, then everyone else can use this product on this machine. So switching to different users makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just published updated HOWTO documents for authentication, specifically targetting Microsoft accounts.  Take a look at the Quickstart guides for your platform at https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps for details.

short version - MSA no longer uses Microsoft Account (which is deprecated) - it's done through Azure Active Directory now.